# Trying to edit .css file on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the styling of some elements on my wordpress blog. Just a quick rundown of my set up. I have an ec2 micro instance running on bitnami/AWS.

when i use firebug to inspect the element it usually says style.css (line number).

but for some reason the text in the element that I'm trying to edit refers to a "/wordpress/ #4 (line number)" file.

I can't seem to locate the file anywhere.

i tried using

```
    grep -rl "string" /path
```

at the command line to match the string and i found a file that matches that string. when i go to change the color value in the file, the site still doesn't update.

Can anyone here tell me were I can find the "/wordpress/ #4" file in my bitnami stack?

Comment: Can someone translate this to English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in `wordpress/wp_content/themes/your-theme`.

More info on Wordpress' file structure: http://www.howtospoter.com/web-20/wordpress/wordpress-guide-dissection-of-file-structure

Comment: i've checked in the style.css file and that class styling doesn't exist there